# Building paragraph tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to add a paragraph to my soup. The paragraph should look like -

```
<p class="test-class"><strong>TEST MESSAGE</strong></p>
```

I already have a working code that does this.

```
paragraphTag = soup.new_tag('p')
paragraphTag['class'] = 'test-class'
strongTag = soup.new_tag('strong')
strongTag.append('TEST MESSAGE')
paragraphTag.append(strongTag)
paragraph.insert_before(paragraphTag)
```

Note that insert_before is purposely done since this is part of bigger code where I need insert_before.

My question is - Is there any better way to do this? Or Is there any smaller piece of code that I can write to achieve this? Also please note that I tried putting everything in one string and added that to paragraph. But then when I used find_all to search for all p 
tags this newly added p tag was getting skipped. So I guess it really did not get properly added.

Any input would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build your snippet as HTML in a *new* `BeautifulSoup()` object:

```
html = '<p class="test-class"><strong>TEST MESSAGE</strong></p>'
snippet = BeautifulSoup(html).p.extract()
paragraph.insert_before(snippet)
```

The `.extract()` call makes this work; it detaches the elements from their host document object model.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body/></html>')
>>> html = '<p class="test-class"><strong>TEST MESSAGE</strong></p>'
>>> snippet = BeautifulSoup(html).p.extract()
>>> snippet
<p class="test-class"><strong>TEST MESSAGE</strong></p>
>>> soup.body.append(snippet)
>>> soup
<html><body><p class="test-class"><strong>TEST MESSAGE</strong></p></body></html>
```